# mysql grouping problem

Tags: mysql, group-by

I have the following table:

```
date1              date2       sc   cash    date
"2010-09-20"    "2010-09-21"    202 300 "2010-03-01"
"2010-09-20"    "2010-09-21"    202 600 "2010-08-01"
"2010-09-20"    "2010-09-21"    202 670 "2010-08-20"
"2010-09-20"    "2010-09-21"    202 710 "2010-09-01"
"2010-09-20"    "2010-09-21"    202 870 "2010-09-21"
"2010-09-21"    "2010-09-22"    199 300 "2010-03-01"
"2010-09-21"    "2010-09-22"    199 600 "2010-08-01"
"2010-09-21"    "2010-09-22"    199 670 "2010-08-20"
"2010-09-21"    "2010-09-22"    199 710 "2010-09-01"
"2010-09-21"    "2010-09-22"    199 870 "2010-09-21"
```

What is to group by `(date1,date2)` and `(cash,date)` such that `date = max(date <= date1)`

```
date1              date2       sc   cash    date
"2010-09-20"    "2010-09-21"    202 870 "2010-09-21"
"2010-09-21"    "2010-09-22"    199 870 "2010-09-21"
```

Comment: what datatype are your date fields? You're not using VARCHAR are you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

what you need is to use the **HAVING** clause... i'll just assume that you have an id on each row.. (if you don't, you'll have to modify my query, but it'll be harder =D )

```
SELECT date1,date2,sc,cash,date
FROM mytable 
WHERE id IN (SELECT id
             FROM mytable GROUP BY date1,date2
             HAVING max(date)>=date1)
```

i've tested it in Postgresql and works fine.Sorry, I haven't been able to test it in MySql

Good Luck

Comment: Thank you so much man , it worked with kinda the same idea :)